# Profiling in Bootstrap.yaml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am working on a bootstrap.yaml, where I want profiling.

Please find my current yaml file.

```
spring:
    application:
        name:app-name
        
wf:
    keystore:
        file: file:///prodcert.jks
        password:'abcd'
    trustStore:
        file: file:///prodTrustStore.jks
        password:'abcd'
    keyStoreType:JKS
```

Everything in my yaml needs to be same, except the `keystore and truststore` not sure, how do I profile that and ensure I can have it on the same file.

Answer (score 0):

you can have different profiles in `application.yml` with corresponding properties & values to each profile

```
#Used for all profiles & keystore, trustStore are optional here

logging.level:
org.springframework: INFO
wf:
   keystore:
     file: file:///dev.jks
     password: 'dev'
   trustStore:
     file: file:///dev.jks
     password: 'dev'
   keyStoreType:JKS

#'dev' profile only
---

spring.profiles: dev
wf:
   keystore:
     file: file:///dev.jks
     password: 'dev'
   trustStore:
     file: file:///dev.jks
     password: 'dev'

#'prod' profile only

---

spring.profiles: prod
wf:
   keystore:
     file: file:///prod.jks
     password: 'prod'
   trustStore:
     file: file:///prod.jks
     password: 'prod'
```